# Submit form and retrieve result using Dojo

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, dojo

Could anyone provide a simple example how to ajaxify a form with dojo and retrieve a result from a php script?

like

```
<form action="login.php" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="user">
  <input type="password" name="password">
  <input type="button" value="login">
</form>
```

**+**

```
<?PHP
if($_POST["user"] == "test" && $_POST["password"] == "test") {
  echo "youre logged in successfully [REDIRECT HERE]";
}
else {
  echo "you failed epic";
}
?>
```

**+**

`dojo.xhrpost` or what?!

Comment: StackOverflow is a very welcoming comunity. You don't need to say you are despaired or use CAPS to get help...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

xhrPOST - for example

```
// Local var representing if the form has been sent at all
var hasBeenSent = false;
// Local var representing node to be updated
var messageNode = dojo.byId("messageNode");
// Using dojo.xhrPost, as the amount of data sent could be large
dojo.xhrPost({
    // The URL of the request
    url: "submission.php",
    // No content property -- just send the entire form
    form: dojo.byId("contactForm"),
    // The success handler
    load: function(response) {
        messageNode.innerHTML = "Thank you for contacting us!";
    },
    // The error handler
    error: function() {
        messageNode.innerHTML = "Your message could not be sent, please try again."
    },
    // The complete handler
    handle: function() {
        hasBeenSent = true;
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you! I of course had a look at the documentation, too. But I can't see where the output of the php-script is beeing retrieved?

Comment: change the code like this - `load: function(response) {
        messageNode.innerHTML = response;
},` The **response** is your php line :)